# Are the different definitions of rational maps on varieties equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is the definition of a rational map on a projective (or affine) variety given in Miles Reid’s undergraduate algebraic geometry:

> ### 5.6 Rational maps and morphisms
>
> Rational maps between projective (or affine) varieties are defined using $k(V)$: if $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is an irreducible algebraic set, a rational map $V \dashrightarrow \mathbb{A}^m$ is a (partially defined) map given by $P \mapsto (f_1(P), \dotsc, f_m(P))$, where $f_1, \dotsc, f_m \in k(V)$.
> A rational map $V \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$ is defined by $P \mapsto (f_0(P) : \dotsb : f_m(P))$ where $f_0, f_1, \dotsc, f_m \in k(V)$.
> Notice that if $g \in k(V)$ is a nonzero element, then $g f_0, g f_1, \dotsc, g f_m$ defined the same rational map.
> Therefore (assuming that $V$ does not map into the smaller projective space $(X_0 = 0)$), it would be possible to assume throughout that $f_0 = 1$.
>
> Clearly then, there is a bijection between the two sets
> $$
>   \{ \text{rational maps $f \colon V \dashrightarrow \mathbb{A}^m \subset \mathbb{P}^m$} \}
> $$
> and
> $$
>   \{ \text{rational maps $f \colon V \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$} \mid f(V) \not\subset (X_0 = 0) \} \,,
> $$
> since either kind of maps is given by $m$ elemenst $f_i \in k(V)$.
>
> ([Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWvS2.png))

I want to ask if this definition is equivalent to the definition where a rational map is defined as an equivalence class of morphisms on open subsets? And how are these two definitions related?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are equivalent because you are regarding the elements of $k(V)$ as regular maps on an open subset to the affine line, modulo and equivalence relation.

Now, taking into account that a map is regular if and only if it is so componentwise, it is clear that every rational map according to the definition in the reference is a rational map according to you. For the converse, just take as domain of your rational map a distinguished open $V_f$, with $f$ a convenient homogeneous polynomial; then your map takes the form $(f_0,…,f_n)$, for certain $f_i\in k(V)$.